# NFS problems: freezes

Tags: 20.10, nfs, streaming

I've been stumped by recent problems I've been experiencing while streaming content from NFS shares on a CoreELEC box (Kodi 18.9). Until about 3 to 4 weeks ago, I was able to play content (HD or UHD) without any problems, stuttering or else. I was able to seek forward or backward and the media swould start playing again instantly. I was a perfect camper. But when I came back from holiday, I started having stuttering, mini freezes, while playing video files. Seeking a couple times would totally hang the box and I'd have to wait to regain control of it. Then while I was trawling the net for answers, I had a hunch it might be related to recent OS updates. The only significant change, I think, was the upgrade to newer kernels via apt upgrade. So I decided to load an older kernel (5.8.0-48-generic) just for fun and out of desperation. Bingo! No more freezes or stuttering when playing videos.
My question then is as follows. Did any of you experience the same problems and is there a way/workaround to upgrade to the latest kernels, for security reasons, while avoiding the misery? This is clearly a regression brought in after kernel 5.8.0-48.
Thanks for taking the time.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question and maybe help others. I had some time to tinker with more recent kernels and found out that at least starting with kernel 5.10 all my woes are gone. Did not troubleshoot the issue with all kernels since, mind you, just found a working one and confirmed that problems had indeed been introduced with some iterations of the 5.8 version, in combination with the pair CoreELEC/Kodi 18.9 streaming from NFS. Problem solved for now then. Will try more recent kernels soon.